# How did GamerFood hack the Starcraft IEM Taipei Tournament?

Tags: exploit

During the recently completed professional Starcraft tournament, Intel Extreme Masters (IEM) Taipei 2015, the notorious cheat software company Team Gamer Food hacked the cast somehow. How did they do it? I have included a screen shot below showing the hack:

[image]

Just to give the background on this for people unfamiliar with the domain, for some time now Gamer Food has been hacking CounterStrike and Half Life tournaments with advertisements. The way they do this is by setting up private servers with names very similar to popular servers. If you play on their server, they use admin privileges to replace your configuration. The substituted configuration then changes your keybinding, so you click the wrong key and bam ads start appearing on the screen that everybody sees. Doing this they have been a plague on pro CounterStrike tournaments and other FPS venues.

HOWEVER, Starcraft does not work like this. There are normally no private servers. Everyone uses Blizzard servers, so the FPS private server trick does not work.

So, the question is how are they doing it?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like observer chat so I would guess it is most likely the result of a password compromise. Either the tournament password or one of the official observer accounts used to televise/stream/shoutcast the game.